# characterization of finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ by maximal ideals

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I need to show the following problem

if $K$ is any finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$, then there exists an integer $n$ and a maximal ideal $M$ of the $n$ variable polynomial ring $\mathbb{Q}[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$ such that

$K \simeq \mathbb{Q}[x_1,\cdots,x_n]/M $.

I think since $K$ is a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$, then there is a basis $\{\alpha_1, \cdots,\alpha_n\}$ for $K$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$, for some $n$. Moreover, $\alpha_i$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$ for each $i$.

I am not quite sure how to prove the existence of the maximal ideal.

Comment: You've described a surjective map from a polynomial ring over $\mathbb{Q}$ to $K$. What can you say about its kernel?

Comment: @AndrewDudzik, it is maximal ideal, right?

Comment: It is, but why?

Comment: @AndrewDudzik, because it contains all polynomials whose zeros are the algebraic elements $\alpha_i$'s, right?

Comment: @AndrewDudzik, I am not sure how to show it is ring homomorphism!